# MS SQL Server JDBC Driver does not read remarks

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, liquibase

I am trying to read the DB metadata for use with liquibase dbdoc from an SQL Server. However, it seems that neither

- MS SQL Server JDBC driver (sqljdbc4-4.0.2206.100.jar)

nor

- jTDS Sql Server JDB Driver (http://jtds.sourceforge.net/)

support reading the MS SQL column/table "description" field from an SQL Server via Column.getRemarks().

Does anyone know whether there is some alternative driver that I could use?

Comment: I have a feeling your question is very high-level. Where are you trying to read db metadata from, is it INFORMATION_SCHEMA?

Comment: I can't answer your question, but you might want to clarify exactly what you mean by "remarks" or the "description field". I suspect you mean [extended properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243(v=sql.105).aspx), but I may be wrong. If you're not sure what to call it, just mention exactly where you can see it.

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear. The jdbc drivers Column object has a remarks field (getRemarks()) which I would have thought might return the "description" field from ms SQL. But unfortunately this is not the case. Therefore, when generating db documentation via liquibase this field is not properly evaluated and the documentation is not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a sp which reads description using `sys.extended_properties` and call the sp to get the extended properties.

Comment: while this would be possible, it is quite unfortunate that neither of the drivers transparently support this. This makes using libraries which build on top of JDBC awkward to use (e.g. Liquibase) since you would need to patch these libraries too.

Comment: I guess the reason JDBC driver doesn't have this is because  extended properties is not something which is common in all relational databases. Extended properties are specific to SQL server while JDBC targets all relational databases.